# Finding biggest number in array returns max int value

Tags: c++

I want to find the biggest and lowest numbers in array using a function. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void findLowHigh(int* numbers, int size, int* min, int* max) {
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (*min > numbers[i]) *min = numbers[i];
        else if (*max < numbers[i]) *max = numbers[i];
    }
}

int main() {
    printf("##### Find lowest and highest number in collection #####");
    printf("\n Array checked: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ]");
    int min, max;
    int numbers1[10] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    findLowHigh(numbers1, 10, &min, &max);
    printf("\nMin: %d\nMax: %d", min, max);

    printf("\n Array checked: [ 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 ]");
    int numbers2[10] = { 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };
    findLowHigh(numbers2, 10, &min, &max);
    printf("\nMin: %d\nMax: %d", min, max);

    return 0;
}
```

And there's output:

```
##### Find lowest and highest number in collection #####
Array checked: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ]
Min: 1
Max: 32767
Array checked: [ 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 ]
Min: 1
Max: 32767
Process finished with exit code 0
```

I'm guessing there's something wrong with pointers, but what is it?

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: Your variables are not initialised so it's being set to some unitialised value which in your case is 32767 so it's never true that max is less than any of your values in your array. You should initialise both to some sensible value like `0` or whatever

Comment: where do you initialize low and high?

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks, I'll learn from that.

Comment: You can also just use the function provided in the standard library: `std::array<int, 10> numbers1{...};` and then `const auto minAndMax = std::minmax_element(numbers1.begin(), numbers1.end());`

Comment: @RyanP I know, but I wanted to write the solution by myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if (*min > numbers[i])` Assume `*min` already contains a legal value.

But you don't initialize the integer whose address you pass. A possible fix (after including `limits.h` (or `climits`, if you *really* are compiling C++) ):

```
int min=INT_MAX;
int max=INT_MIN;
```

---

As **Nathan Oliver** suggested in the comments. A more robust solution would be to set `min` and `max` to the first element of the array.

```
if (min && max && numbers && size > 0) {
  *min = numbers[0];
  *max = numbers[0];
}
```

Comment: Then the function will always return `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX` as min and max.

Comment: @KrzysztofKraszewski And you can't have that `else` there... or at least not for `i == 0`.

Comment: @KrzysztofKraszewski - No it won't. any integer is less than `INT_MAX`. So `numbers[0]` will immediately be chosen as the new min.

Comment: @StoryTeller Sorry, you're right. I misread it as `int min = INT_MIN`, which makes no sense. Thank you, that was a silly mistake on my side.

Comment: personally I would use `min = max = numbers[0];` in the function and then start the for loop at 1 instead of 0.  This handles cases where the array is of size 1 for you.

Comment: This solution places a burden on the function's user to reset min and max before each call. It would improve usability if findLowHigh took the responsibility of assigning initial values.

Comment: @StoryTeller No reason to use an `if`.  Just change the function to start like `min = max = numbers[0]; for(int i = 1; i < size; i++) ...`

Comment: @NathanOliver - The OP passes `min` and `max` as pointers to output parameters. I'd be remiss if I didn't check for nullity before dereferencing.

Comment: @StoryTeller Oh good call.  To used to passing by reference.  In that case I would also change the function signature to take references as well :)  It also makes the calling code easier.

Comment: @NathanOliver - I agree wholeheartedly. But I have a strong suspicion the C++ tag is misplaced, and would like the code to remain valid even if the tag is changed.

Answer (score 2):

You should initialize your min/max:

```
int min, max;
```

like:

```
int min=INT_MAX, max=INT_MIN;
```

More in c++ style you would use `#include <limits>` and:

```
int min = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
int max = std::numeric_limits<int>::min();
```

[edit]

You should also (as it was in comments) remove the `else` in your logic from:

```
if (*min > numbers[i]) *min = numbers[i];
    else if (*max < numbers[i]) *max = numbers[i];
```

otherwise you may never find a max value in your results.

Answer (score 1):

As you are comparing with value of min and max, before passing the value to function you should initialise the values min=INT_MAX and max=INT_MIN.

Answer (score 1):

`int min, max;` are uninitialized, they can contain any value. You should initialize at the beginning of `findLowHigh`. It's important to reset them before you call findLowHigh or past results will have an impact on future results.

You can simply set them both to the first element of `numbers` and skip that element in your loop. Make sure to check that `size` is non-zero first.

```
void findLowHigh(int* numbers, int size, int* min, int* max) 
{
    if(size > 0)
    {
        *min = numbers[0];
        *max = numbers[0];

        for(int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
            if (*min > numbers[i]) *min = numbers[i];
            if (*max < numbers[i]) *max = numbers[i]; // Also, remove this else
        }
    }
}
```

Edit : You'll have to decide what should happen in case `size` is zero. What is the min and max of an empty list?

Answer (score 0):

When you initialize your variables like `int min, max;` you leave them blank instead of a number, this means that min and max is automatically set as undefined numbers.

Comment: nope - min,max contain random (undefined) value if not initialized

Comment: @marcinj actually it does not matter which values min max would contain as program would have UB.